# Quadratic fitted line doesn't appear in R plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, surface, quadratic

When I run following script in R, the fitted line doesn't appear in the plot. I want it to appear though. Can you help me?

```
rm(list=ls())
# Surface tension
surft <- c(49.1, 51.7, 50.7, 52.0, 53.5, 52.9, 55.1, 59, 62.5, 66.4, 69.0, 73.8) # surface tension of mixtures

# Mole fractions
M1 <- c(62.0678) # Molar mass ethylene glycol
M2 <- c(18.01528) # Molar mass water
m1 <- c(20, 19.3474, 19.3727, 14.4605, 16.9556, 17.9408, 16.0283, 11.6572, 7.5394, 5.0984, 2.0971, 0) # mass of ethylene glycol in mixture
m2 <- c(0, 0.4192, 1.0761, 1.3379, 2.3457, 3.5900, 6.3889, 12.0517, 11.8217, 18.4019, 17.0114, 20) # mass of water in mixture
mf <- c((m1*M2)/(m1*M2+m2*M1)) # mole fractions ethylene glycol
mfwater <- c((m2*M1)/(m2*M1+m1*M2))

# Plot surface tension / mole fraction
plot(mf, surft, type="p", xlab="Mole fraction ethylene glycol", ylab="Surface tension / mN/m")

#Fitting with Connors-Wright Model
#a <- c(1)
#b <- c(1)
#surftfit <- c((1+(a*mfwater)/(1-b*mfwater))*mf)
#lines(mf, surftfit)

fit <- lm(mf ~ surft + I(surft^2))
fitted <- 0.002355*mf^2-0.329045*mf+11.492344
lines(mf, fitted)
```

ggplot2 is awesome, I really appreciate your help. I have following code now:

```
rm(list=ls())
# Surface tension
surft <- c(49.1, 51.7, 50.7, 52.0, 53.5, 52.9, 55.1, 59, 62.5, 66.4, 69.0, 73.8) # surface tension of mixtures

dev <- c(2.04229, 0.55532, 0.76122, 0.52876, 0.72262, 1.67266, 1.49312, 0.55022, 
0.42132, 0.97973, 0.32890, 0.38697)  #standard deviation


# Mole fractions
M1 <- c(62.0678) # Molar mass ethylene glycol
M2 <- c(18.01528) # Molar mass water
m1 <- c(20, 19.3474, 19.3727, 14.4605, 16.9556, 17.9408, 16.0283, 11.6572, 7.5394, 5.0984, 2.0971, 0) # mass of ethylene glycol in mixture
m2 <- c(0, 0.4192, 1.0761, 1.3379, 2.3457, 3.5900, 6.3889, 12.0517, 11.8217, 18.4019, 17.0114, 20) # mass of water in mixture
mf <- c((m1*M2)/(m1*M2+m2*M1)) # mole fractions ethylene glycol
mfwater <- c((m2*M1)/(m2*M1+m1*M2))


# Plot surface tension / mole fraction
#plot(mf, surft, type="p", xlab="Mole fraction ethylene glycol", ylab="Surface tension / mN/m")



fit <- lm(mf ~ surft + I(surft^2))
#fitted <- 0.002355*mf^2-0.329045*mf+11.492344
#lines(mf, fitted)

#Fitting with Connors-Wright Model
#a <- c(0.9)
#b <- c(0.5)
#surftfit <- c((1+(a*mfwater)/(1-b*mfwater))*mf)
#lines(mf~surft, col="red")

#plot(mf, surft, type="p", xlab="Mole fraction ethylene glycol", ylab="Surface tension / mN/m")
#ft = fitted(fit)
#lines(mf, ft)
dd <-data.frame(mf,surft)
ggplot(dd, aes(x=mf, y = surft))+geom_point()+stat_smooth(method="lm", formula = y~x+I(x^2))
```

How can I show the standard deviation in the plot in form of error bars?
And another question: The quadratic fit doesn't seem to be omtpimal for this points. I guess a fit in the form of y=1/x (hyperbola) for 0<=x<=1 would be a better fit. How can I fit this hyperbola?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there a lot of things that does not work in your code, so it is not clear what you want to do or what you are trying to fit. You should try this code

```
plot(surft, mf, type="p", xlab="Mole fraction ethylene glycol", ylab="Surface tension / mN/m")
ft = fitted(fit)
lines(surft, ft)
```

Comment: Hi, with **ggplot**,  the diagram is quiet better, you should try this **ggplot(dd, aes(x=surft, y = mf))+geom_point()+stat_smooth(method="lm", formula = y~x+I(x^2))**

Comment: Ok thanks, I haven't installed ggplot2 yet. I need to read myself into ggplot2.

Comment: `dd <-data.frame(surft,mf)` I guess